# Okta integration for iOS, Android & Web

Tags: react-native, okta, react-native-web

Is there any way to integrate Okta react native project common code for iOS, Android, Web platform?

Comment: I've done it with React Native AppAuth for iOS and Android, but not for web. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/16/build-react-native-authentication-oauth-2 I'm not sure that React Native AppAuth support web.

Comment: web with react-native: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth , it even has a sample Okta config. Of course, you don't have to use React Native with AppAuth.

Comment: @Sunil did you find a common method?